# Perl - load records from file into hash

Tags: perl, file, hash, records

Is it possible to load records from a file straight into a hash please?  The records are delimited with /begin and /end, and have a fixed order of content.

What I want is a hash populated like this:

```
hash_city{London}{slurped_record}='/begin CITY London\n   big\n   England\n   Sterling\n/end CITY'
hash_city{Paris}{slurped_record}='/begin CITY\n   Paris\n   big\n   France\n   Euro\n/end CITY'
hash_city{Melbourne}{slurped_record}='/begin CITY\n\n   Melbourne\n   big\n   Australia\n   Dollar\n   hot\n/end CITY'
```

I can then go off and process the records in the hash etc.. (reason for the 'slurped_record' entry is later I want to add new keys to say London like, 'country=England' etc

```
hash_city{London}{Country}='England'
```

I've managed to achieve something that works by slurping instead of reading the file line-by-line.  Matching on a /begin, building up a record ($rec.=$_), then matching on a /end and processing.  It's a bit messy and wondered if there was a more elegant Perl approach..

My code attempt so far is as follows:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $string = do {local $/; <DATA>};
my %hash_city = map{$2=>$1} $string =~ /(\/begin\s+CITY\s+(\w+).+\/end\s+CITY)/smg;
print Dumper(%hash_city);

__DATA__
stuff
stuff
/begin CITY London
   big
   England
   Sterling
/end CITY

stuff
stuff

/begin CITY
   Paris
   big
   France
   Euro
/end CITY
stuff

/begin CITY

   Melbourne
   big
   Australia
   Dollar
   hot
/end CITY

stuff
```

Comment: Your slurp generates two copies of the file contents, and is better written as `my $string; {local $/; $string = <DATA>;}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Made a little program to show the other way around, advancing your process as well. ) Don't know whether is't elegant or not, but I suppose it gets the job done. )

```
my %city_record;

## we're going to process the input file in chunks.
## here we define the chunk start marker, and make Perl to separate file input with it
local $/ = "/begin CITY";

# ignoring anything before the first section starts
scalar <DATA>;

while (<DATA>) {
  # throwing out anything after the section end marker
  # (might be done with substr-index combo as well, 
  # but regex way was shorter and, for me, more readable as well )
  my ($section_body) = m{^(.+)/end CITY}ms;

  # now we're free to parse the section_body as we want. 
  # showing here pulling city name - and the remaining data, by using the split special case
  my ($city, @city_data) = split ' ', $section_body;

  # filling out all the fields at once
  # (may seem a bit unusual, but it's a simple hash slice actually, great Perl idiom)
  @{ $city_record{$city} }{qw/ size country currency misc /} = @city_data;
}

# just to test, use something of yours instead. )
print Dumper \%city_record;
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back but thank you for taking the time to respond here.  This is an excellent answer and has helped me a lot with my Perl scripting, not only in this example but with other files I'm parse too.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably make use of the [flip-flop operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators): `/FROM/ .. /TO/`. You can use a different delimiter to make the regex more readable. I'm using `m#^/begin ...#` below. Extracting the city name is simple, assuming there is only whitespace between the header and the city name. I am using `\S` (non-whitespace), since you don't want to miss city names with non-alphanumerics in the name, like "Foo-Bar" or "St.Tropez".

If you do find city names that contain whitespace, you may need to figure out a better regex to find the city name. I'll leave that as an exercise.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash;
my $string;
while (<DATA>) {
    if (m#^/begin CITY# .. m#^/end CITY#) {
        $string .= $_;
        if (m#^/end CITY#) {
            my ($city) = $string =~ m#^/begin CITY\s*(\S+)#;
            $hash{$city}{slurp} = $string;
            $string = "";
        }
    }
}
$Data::Dumper::Useqq=1;
print Dumper(\%hash);
```

Comment: *"weird names that contain whitespace"* like `Santa Fe`, `Salt Lake City`, `Baton Rouge` ...

Comment: @Borodin `New York`, `Washington D.C.`, `Kuala Lumpur`. Yeah, now I can think of tons of them, but when I wrote the answer, I totally blanked.

Answer (score 0):

This would give you a [hash with all cities and their properties](http://pastebin.com/yNkrRjbb):

```
my %cities = map {
    my($name, @data, %props) = (split ' ');
    @props{qw(Size Country Currency Temperature)} = @data;
    $name => \%props
} $string =~ m|
    ^/begin \s+ CITY
    (.+?)
    ^/end \s+ CITY
|gsmx;

print Dumper(\%cities);
```